# Getting an error while using Django Model Form in views.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

In my models.py

```
 class Alert(models.Model):

    user = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    a = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "'%s' at %s" % (self.user)
```

In My forms.py:

```
 class AlertForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Alert
        fields = ('a','user')
        widgets = {
            'user': forms.HiddenInput()
        }

AlertCountFormset = modelformset_factory(Alert,
                                        form = AlertForm)
```

In my views.py:

```
def profile_setting(request, slug):
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = AlertForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        alert_form = form.save(commit=False)
        alert_form.user = request.user.username
        alert_form.save() # Here i am getting the error
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/list')

extra_context = {
    'form': AlertForm()
}
return direct_to_template(request,'users/profile_setting.html',
                          extra_context)
```

I am trying to fill the Django model Form but i am getting following `error` where i had put the comment:

```
events_alertcount.a may not be NULL
```

What is this? Even after putting the`null=True` in the field of `a` it shows an same error. Is that something wrong with my `forms.py or models.py`?

Comment: You also have a mistake in the snippet of your view code not that it matters. But you are checking the request again GET and collecting the form from POST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is enforced on database level, too. Set your "a" column in your db to allow the field to be NULL. This should fix it. HTH.

Comment: I didn't got you. Are you asking me to do this ***a = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)*** ?

Comment: yes, you have to declare this on 'a'. If you ran syncdb without null=True your db will have set the field to not accept NULL as value. So you have to change your db column to accept NULL as value. You can also delete the db tables and run syncdb again after you changed a to a = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True). But please make a backup before you delete tables when they are already filled with your data.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
a = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and you should call syncdb once again

Comment: syncdb does not change existing db tables!

Answer (score 2):

When defining a model field, the `blank` option is validation related, meaning that if you set `blank` to true, validation will not fail if that field is not filled in.

> `blank` is validation-related. If a field has `blank=True`, validation on Django’s admin site will allow entry of an empty value. If a field has `blank=False`, the field will be required.

However, if validation doesn't fail and you save the model, the field will be persisted to the database. Now, a field cannot be `null` in the database unless you set the `null` option to true.

> `null` is purely database-related, whereas blank is validation-related.

Having said that, you can fix you error by adding the null option to `Alert.a`:

```
a = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Now, if you've already ran the `syncdb` command, you need to drop your tables and then rerun `syncdb` in order for this change to be picked up. If this database is a production database and you cannot do this, look into [django-south](http://south.aeracode.org/) on how you can migrate your schemas and data.