# Django Form: Hidden Field Error When Submitting Form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-views

I have hidden field that saves when an article is created and also another hidden field that tells the articles status:
**forms.py**:

```
class SavedArticles(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields =['title', 'content', 'status', 'time_created','publisher']
        widgets = {
            'status': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'time_created': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

The content of `time_created` and `status` will be provided by me at the backend:

```
def publish(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        article = SavedArticles(request.POST or None)
        if article.is_valid():      
            article = article.save(commit = False)
            article.status = 0 #have tried articles.data['status'] = 0
            article.time_created = timezone.now() #have tried articles.data['time_created'] = 0
            article.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('mysite:home'))
```

My routes are fine but whenever I feel the form submits I get the following error:

```
(Hidden field status) This field is required.
(Hidden field time_created) This field is required.
```

What am I doing **WRONG**? I have tried I could all day.

Comment: If the values for `time_created` and `status` will be supplied in your view, why are you passing them in from your form? Without initial values, if those fields aren't specified as `blank=True` on your model, the form won't validate.

Comment: You are right as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11261338/3009875. Thank you.

Comment: You want to post an answer so I can accept it to avoid further comments or answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying a ModelForm, if fields are present in the POST data, that aren't specified in the `fields` list/tuple, Django will attempt to hydrate a model instance based on the data in the POST, regardless if the fields aren't specified on the ModelForm.

If no initial data is supplied to the form class, and the form inputs have no values AND the fields on the model aren't specified as `blank=True`, the form validation will fail.